# The best way to accomplish Ajax Feeds

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, feed

I'm currently starting a new project that will display user distrubuted data links in an ajax feed on front end.

What I'm looking to accomplish is very similar to the to the Facebook Feeds on there index, where the content is updated every X Seconds.

I already have half of the PHP side completed such as the Entities Compiler etc, But what I am looking to find out is

"What is the best way to accomplish this"

I'm taking into consideration the following

- The Dom's sensitivity
- Polling back end to wait for enough new feeds before update
- Security
- Speed and Bandwidth. Both User and Server.

I'm going to start a new JS library system that will control data flows **from** and **to** the server as well as GUI, but it will be built to incorporate other libraries such as `jQuery`, `prototype` etc.

Any advice on this would be appreciated !

Rob

Comment: Start here: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: I totally understand ajax mate, what im asking for is the best way to accomplsih the situation, should I poll the server, How can I avoid DOM Overflows etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the [Prototype JS Periodical updater](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/ajax/periodicalupdater/) would perfectly fit your requirements. I used it on a forum project for school, and it's really easy to implement. Just give it the adress of the PHP script that loads content from the database, and he will go get it, and replace/prepend/append it to the area of your choice. You can even set up a decay.

Hope I have helped.